# Hide WIFI Password in KDE

Tags: wireless, network-manager, kde

I am trying to setup a system for multiple users and multiple laptops which automatically connect to a set WIFI without allowing the users to see the WIFI password. I am using **knetworkmanager** and can't find any option to not show the password.

(I used to use **nm-applet**, there you could connect as root and enable for other users, I can't find anything comparable in KDE)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: While very old this likely will work for what you need: https://askubuntu.com/questions/69317/need-to-disable-show-password-in-wireless